# Sobre "sinalizadores"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução

Não acredito que haja uma alma sequer no site que concorde que *"sinalizador"* é uma boa tradução para nossas queridas *"flags"*. *Flag* é um termo comum o suficiente para ser adotado aqui sem que niguém fique se perguntando o que ele quer dizer.

## Nem tudo são flores...

Nem todo uso de *flag* no site é um substativo. Há vários verbos no processo, verbos que precisam ser conjugados, e [*flagar*, *flagou*, *flaguei*] são muito mais esquisitos escritos do que falados...

O que eu quero dizer é que precisa mudar, *flag* é uma opção bastante viável mas tratá-la como verbo pode ser bastante estranho de ler.

Alguém tem algum problema com isso? Alguma sugestão melhor? O que vocês acham?

Comment: flagrar, flagrou, flagrei? =)

Comment: acho que cabe: http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/flagrar

Answer (score 10):

O verbo falado de uma palavra que na verdade é inglesa também fica horrível, não é só escrita não. :) Nesse caso parece até que o Cebolinha (personagem de quadrinho do Maurício de Souza) está falando outra coisa.

Acho que alguém pode sugerir algo melhor, mas nesse momento o que me vem à mente é **alertar**. Mais curto e indica bem o que estamos tentando fazer.

Até gosto também do *denunciar* apesar de ser um pouco mais longo e ser mais duro. Até onde eu sei, a *flag* sempre deveria ser usada para denunciar algo errado no site. Tá certo que (só) a última opção quando vamos alertar é apenas para chamar a atenção. As demais é para denunciar. Mas ainda prefiro o *alertar*

Comment: Gostei de "alertar". Fica bom como substantivo (*alerta*) e passa corretamente a idéia.

Answer (score -2):

O termo *sinalizador* me lembra algo relacionado ao trânsito ou então a alguém perdido pedindo ajuda.

Por outro lado o verbo *sinalizar* faz sentido no [contexto de uma flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) porque, a meu ver, quando estamos *sinalizando* algo é porque queremos passar alguma mensagem e evidenciá-la. O problema é que *sinalizar* pode ser no sentido tanto positivo quanto negativo.

Outro verbo que faz sentido, ainda no contexto, é *denunciar*. Este, particularmente, acredito que seja o mais intuitivo para o brasileiro, já que é usado em grandes sites. É uma pena que não faça jus ao sentido original.

Pessoalmente, acharia ruim ver esses neologismos (*flagar, flagou, flaguei*) escritos em algum lugar. Simplesmente parece errado!

Comment: Não gosto de "denunciar"... Parece algo muito mais grave do que uma flag realmente é. O sentido mais próximo que consigo é de "marcar" (como spam, como duplicata, etc) mas é um verbo que, sozinho, não faz muito sentido

Comment: Lembrei agora de uma discussão sobre a tradução da palavra *Issues* para o BitBucket que não teve fim. Nesses casos talvez seja melhor eleger algumas palavras candidatas e fazer uma votação com pessoas competentes.

Answer (score -3):

Gostei da idéia do @gabe: **marcar**

Outra palavra que acho interessante: **indicar**

Indicar como spam.

Indicar como ofensivo.

Indicar como duplicata.

Comment: Apesar de "marcar" ter sido idéia minha, e "indicar" não ser nada ruim, eu não acho que se encaixe com todas as vezes em que "flag" é usado (imagine um link "indicar"/"marcar" embaixo de todo post... Não é intuitivo para um usuário novo o que ele faz). Até agora a minha favorita foi "alerta"