# Tradução na página de sinalizadores

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Apesar da **[discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/69/sobre-sinalizadores)** sobre o termo "sinalizadores" está em aberto, acredito que uma tradução correta já pode ser debatida para o restante da página em:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/[id usuário]

No próprio título que é exibido no navegador acho que cabe uma correção de "Publicações sinalizadas **para** Fulano" para "Publicações sinalizadas **por** Fulano".

Ainda temos:

- **Your flagging history:** Seu histórico de sinalizadores (sinalizações?);
- **moderator attention flags:** sinalizadas para atenção do moderador;
- **comments flagged:** comentários sinalizados;
- **deemed helpful:** considerado útil;
- **declined:** rejeitado;
- **post marked spam:** mensagem marcada como spam;
- **waiting for review:** aguardando análise;
- **disputed:** disputado;
- **posts marked offensive:** mensagens marcadas como ofensiva;
- **comment flagged:** comentário sinalizado;

O que acham que cabe melhor aqui?

Comment: Acrescente na sua lista: `post marked spam`, `waiting for review`, `disputed`, `posts marked offensive`. Tudo isso também pode aparecer na página `Flagged Posts for`.

Comment: Adicionado. Obrigado!